# Lost connection to MS SQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench

My partners have remote SQL server, it on MSSQL 2008 R2. I try to connect on it using MySQLWorkbench. But i've got an error `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60`.

The server side have only this log `[22/Feb/2016 13:48:07] [ID] 307430 [Rule] MSSQL MYCOMPANY [Service] MS-SQL [Connection] TCP 11-111-118-83-my.broadband.net:53376 -> 192.168.0.129:1433 [Duration] 77 sec [Bytes] 324/205/529 [Packets] 6/4/10`.

Why does this error appear? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you sure that MySqlWorkbench supports connections to Sql server?

Comment: No I am not sure, but i didn't found information that it couldn't.

Comment: The name is a giveaway. MySQL is a competing database server to SQL Server. They aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to connect using [SQLPro for MSSQL](http://macsqlclient.com) and everything work fine.